# what happens with a match_parent in a wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was a small question, but unable to find an answer for it. I gave a quick-start on Android training lately and there was a smart question when I was explaining ListViews and Adapters:

I had an example of a layout that represented a row. The root LinearLayout had android:layout_height set to 'match_parent'.

As these views are being added to the ListView, I got the question: "why does the first item not fill the ListView?"

So, why doesn't it? I expect that the ListView will wrap the row in another View that ignores the 'match_parent' and actually effectively changes it to 'wrap_content'. But this is an assumption and was not able (yet) to find the place where this is done in the Android source.